# Rails 5 javascript works only after refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Am new to Rails. i have this in my filename.html.haml file

```
:javascript  
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { 
   //my code;
  });
```

However it works only after i refresh the page, but not working once the page loads. am not using coffee script.

Thanks,

Comment: i referred similar questions and tried, but no luck.,

Comment: don't put js code in views; keep it all in app/assets/javascripts/{anywhere there}

Comment: if i put the js code in app/assets/javascripts/{anywhere}. how to use that in my .haml file(views folder)? can you give me an example.

Comment: Do consider reading about layouts http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html (and all others topics, it'll be helpful). For your specific issue, see at 3.1.2 on the linked page. Also here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when going to the page, if I specify the method as get, the js file is loaded. No refresh is needed.

so do this:

```rb
link_to "new_page", new_page_path, method: :get
```